# Injecting implementation from inherited CRTP to inherited interface class

Tags: c++, interface, c++14, crtp, vtable

I want to get rid of the duplicate code without incurring additional v-table cost.

- `B` is an interface class : it can't be virtual
- `D1` and `D2` are concrete classes of B.

  - Some parts of them are same : shown as  `std::cout<<"same"` in mcve.
  - Some part are different : shown as `different1()` and `different2()`.

Here is the code.  It works OK. ([**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8546db1a5a8d6996))

```
class B{//can't be template
    public: virtual void show()=0;
};
class D1 : public B{
    public: bool different1(){return true;}
    public: virtual void show(){ 
        if( different1() )
            std::cout<<"same";   //duplicate
    }
};
class D2 : public B{
    public: bool different2(){return true;}
    public: virtual void show(){ 
        if( different2() )
            std::cout<<"same";   //duplicate
    }
};
int main(){
    D1 d;
    B* b=&d;
    b->show();  //1 v-table look up : OK!
}
```

### My poor solution (1/2)

Move the duplicate code to the base class (**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17dfbecfcd0a2350)**):-

```
class B{//can't be template
    public: virtual void show(){
        if( differentX() )
            std::cout<<"same";   //duplicate
    }
    public: virtual bool differentX() = 0;
};
class D1 : public B{
    public: bool differentX(){return true;}
};
class D2 : public B{
    public: bool differentX(){return true;}
};
```

The problem is that `b->show()` will incur 2 v-table look-up.  (?)

I know "premature optimization is evil", but I would like to hear if it is possible to reduce the v-table cost to 1. (before take the excuse and use this approach)

### My poor solution (2/2)

Use CRTP  (**[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00598bb668aac246)**)

```
class B{//can't be template
    public: virtual void show()=0;
};
template<class T>class C{  //
    public: bool differentX(){
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->differentImpl()   ;
    }
    public: void show(){
        differentX();
        std::cout<<"same"; 
    }
};
class D1 : public B, public C<D1>{
    public: bool differentImpl(){return true;}
};
class D2 : public B, public C<D2>{
    public: bool differentImpl(){return true;}
};
```

However, it is no longer compliable because `D1` is no longer a concrete class.

How to solve it?  I am new to CRTP.

Comment: whats wrong with solution 1?

Comment: @BЈовић  I believe it costs 2 vtable look-up : both at `show` and `differentX`.

Comment: Obviuosly, for solution 2 to works, your C class must derive from B assuming you want to reuse show code. However, solution 1 would generally be better but it really depends on actual code and usage...

Comment: Bigger costs are for the first call, for 2nd not so big, since ´this´ is loaded in cache. Should be just indirect function call. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Phil1970  It sounds good .... I will investigate about it more.   Thank.

Comment: You can also take the common functionality into a separate function.

Comment: Vtable lookup is not that bad in practice for most cases. In real life code the overhead is often negligeable compared to other executed code. Does a few extra nanoseconds really affect the performance in your case?You would have to execute such code millions of time in a row...

Comment: @BЈовић "this loaded in cache" That is new knowledge for me, thank.    What is "into a separate function"?  How?

Comment: Sorry for probably interrupting this, but I wonder: Why do you write ```public:``` in front of each function?

Comment: @Phil1970 Agree that it is usually not worth. However, in some rare code, I notice it is called quite often. More than anything else, I am curious - I see this pattern many times. It would be great if I can randomly inject function from a CRTP to a random inherit-unrelated interface. ..... As you suggest to make `C<T>` inherit from `B`, is it the only way?

Comment: @Freakyy It is just a personal taste.  I know I don't need it ; it makes me relax.  :)

Answer (score 2):

How's this for a solution?

C implements the show method of B and provides a generic implementation of show that depends on the template parameter T providing an implementation of different.

D1 and D2 inherit from C with themselves as the template parameter.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34e8a727e81e19f7

```
#include <iostream>
class B {//can't be template
    public: virtual void show() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class C : public B {
public:
    void show() override {
        if (Impl().different()) {
            std::cout << "same"; 
        }
    }
private:
    T& Impl() {
        return *static_cast<T*>(this);
    }
};

class D1 : public C<D1> {
    public: bool different() { return true; }
};
class D2 : public C<D2> {
    public: bool different() { return true; }
};

int main() {
    D1 d;
    B* b = &d;
    b->show();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 3 : put the duplicated code in a function. Something like this:

```
class B{//can't be template
    public: virtual void show()=0;
    public: void same(){
        std::cout<<"same";   //no duplicate
    }
};
class D1 : public B{
    public: bool different1(){return true;}
    public: virtual void show(){ 
        if( different1() )
            same();
    }
};
class D2 : public B{
    public: bool different2(){return true;}
    public: virtual void show(){ 
        if( different2() )
            same();
    }
};
int main(){
    D1 d;
    B* b=&d;
    b->show();  //1 v-table look up : OK!
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is base class pollution. In a case with many derived classes, where several are having same functionality, you would have to add many functions in the base class.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, you can create a function, with common functionality:

```
void ShowFuncX( B& b )
{
    if ( b.differentX() )
    {
        std::cout<<"same";
    }
}
```

then in derived:

```
class D1 : public B{
    public: bool different1(){return true;}
    public: virtual void show(){ 
        ShowFuncX( *this );
    }
};
class D2 : public B{
    public: bool different2(){return true;}
    public: virtual void show(){ 
        ShowFuncX( *this );
    }
};
```

---

Also, see "[Is it always a best practice to write a function for anything that needs to repeat twice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/269882/20065)"

Comment: That give me some ideas thank.  Is `differentX()` also declared in `B` as virtual?  How `different1()` and `different2()` are called?

Comment: @cppBeginner `different()`is the virtual method in the base class, no?

Comment: Is this answer based on solution 2?  Should `different1` and `different2` be `differentImpl`?   It is hard to a newbie like me to imagine the rest of the code.

Comment: @cppBeginner No, it is based on solution 1. As you can see, there is no CRPT in this code.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank.